# Non causal zero-phase FIR with the windowing method

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I am trying to design a zero phase non causal FIR filter  with the windowing method in MATLAB .
With the conventional methods it seems i can only obtain linear phase FIR filters .

Also the impulse response is always causal , i use fvtool to analyze the filter maybe is not the right tool for this ?  I noted i get different results with the ( now obsolete) freqzplot .

EDIT : i need the impulse response of the zero phase filter as the input of a function which produces  another FIR .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear phase FIR filter with 2N + 1 coefficients has a constant delay of N samples, so you can just implement such a filter and shift the output backwards in time by N samples and it will then be a non-causal, zero phase filter, as required.

Comment: So there is no 'direct method ' i see ... is it possible instead to shift the impulse response backwards , this way i should obtain the IR of the zero phase , i am right ?

Comment: Sure - you can shift the input signal, the output signal, or the filter itself - it really doesn't matter, so long as you remove the N sample delay somehow.